# BLE+EDR in sleep mode and BT 2.1+EDR

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can a Bluetooth 2.1+EDR module wake a Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy+*Dual Mode* (BLE+EDR) module up, if that is in sleeping mode, if it tries to connect to the BLE+EDR? And can the 2.1+EDR module see the name of BLE+EDR in sleep mode at all?

BLE works together with an other BLE device only, but a BLE+EDR *Dual Mode* works with Classic BT (2.1+EDR) too. My question would be: Could a Classic BT wake up a BLE+EDR Dual Mode device if it is in sleeping mode by trying to connect to it?